# Let scrollbar only appear in the table body

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I use Shadcn and want to create a scrollable Table where the scrollbar is not shown besides the header line. Somehow i cant figure it out how to do it. I am open for any advice! Thank you very much!

This is my code until now...

```
  return (
    <div className={cn('rounded-md border block max-h-96 overflow-auto', className)}>
      <Table>
        <TableHeader className="sticky top-0 backdrop-blur-xl">
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                return (
                  <TableHead key={header.id}>
                    {header.isPlaceholder ? null : flexRender(header.column.columnDef.header, header.getContext())}
                  </TableHead>
                );
              })}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
            table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
              <TableRow key={row.id} data-state={row.getIsSelected() && 'selected'}>
                {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                  <TableCell key={cell.id}>{flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}</TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            ))
          ) : (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell colSpan={columns.length} className="h-24 text-center">
                No results.
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
```

I tried a lot of tailwindcss classes but couldnt get it to work...